# Moving (not flying) object on $x,\ y,\ z$ cartesian axis the latter of which is determined by a graph

Tags: vector-analysis

A surface is determined by the following function :

$x^2 +y^2 +z^4  -z^2 =0 $

The object sits at :$P=(0,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}) $  on the plane only and it can't fly.

The temperature is determined by : $T(x,y,z)=x-\frac{1}{z} $.

I want to schematically draw the path that the object needs to "walk"
in order to reach the maximum temperature available(in every "step" the temperature should increase).

I found that the object needs to start walking in direction of the projection of
the $ \nabla T$ on the normal of the plane which is the $ \nabla T$ itself. which is $ \nabla T(p)=(1,0,2)$.

how can i continue would really appreciate some help ?

Comment: I think the maximum temperature avaible lies on plane. Thus, the vector points in the direction of that maximum temperature retrict to the plane.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 + z^4 - z^2=0$ is a beautiful surface. A kind of lemniscata of revolution. Not a plane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a surface $S(x,y,z)=0$ and a temperature scalar function $T = T(x,y,z)$ the progress direction is obtained by the projection  of $\nabla T = \vec t$ onto the tangent plane to $S$ at the actual point $p_k$ such that $S(p_k)=0$

This projection is given by

$$
\vec u_k = \vec t_k - \hat s_k < \vec t_k, \hat s_k >
$$

Here 
$$
\hat s_k = \frac{\nabla S(p_k)}{||\nabla S(p_k)||}
$$

so the next step is obtained by making

$$
p_{k+1}' = p_k + \delta \hat u_k
$$

The point $p_{k+1}'$ generally does not pertain to $S$ so after the $p_{k+1}'$ computation an approaching iteration should be executed to obtain $p_{k+1} \in S$

In red the initial point and in blue the path to the top.
[image]